# Windows 10 update KB4592438 caused an unexpected reboot exactly one hour after installation

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My PC was rebooted unexpectedly at 11:58, followed by a loading screen of "updating your system". It turns out that the [KB4592438](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4592438/windows-10-update-kb4592438) update was automatically installed in the background on my system.

Setup event log from 10:58:

> A reboot is necessary before package KB4592438 can be changed to the Installed state.

System event log from 12:01:

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

I did not find any information about this. I do not know if I should uninstall this update. What I found is that this phenomenon had [already happened a few months ago](https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/06/24/microsoft-confirms-forced-reboots-bug-windows-10/) with other "Patch Tuesday" updates. Is it recommended to uninstall this update given this circumstance, as advised in this article?

Answer (score 0):

KB4592438 is the December 8, 2020 Patch Tuesday update. It is a regular monthly update and there is no reason to uninstall it. It appears to be working fine - I installed it on both production machines.

Why did it run when it did?  It depends on how you have Windows Updates set to run. Mine are set to run at 3:00am.

If you were updating something else (not necessarily Windows), the pending update would have to run to let the next update happen.

You should review your update settings (Windows Settings, Updates) to determine when you want updates to run. I set working hours / off hours.

From what you have said, all is well.

Comment: On my PC Windows updates are defined to run between 03:00 to 09:00. The thing is that my PC is rarely on during these hours.

Comment: That is fine. The way to handle that is to do (and complete) updates before shutting down. In fact, as long as you save files and take care, you can run updates Patch Tuesday afternoon. That is what I do and it works great. To your question "Is it OK to do the update?"  Yes, the update works fine.